# How can I strip all comments from a Perl script except for the shebang line?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl script that strips comments from other Perl scripts:

```
open (INFILE, $file);
@data = <INFILE>;

foreach $data (@data)
{
    $data =~ s/#.*/ /g;
    print "$data";
}
```

The problem is, this code also removes the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

How can I strip comments except for the shebang?

Comment: You could simply create a variable called `$skip` with a value of `1`. In the first time the code enters the loop, if `$skip` is equal to one, then change the value to 0 and `continue`.

Comment: Your code will also strip code like `$#array`, which is not a comment.

Comment: thank you sir but i would really like to skip the first occurrence and not the first line..

Comment: @tidibur The shebang cannot be on any other line than the first line.

Comment: So how did it go? Did you tell your teacher that he is a noob? :)

Comment: @TLP, since no one got the problem, our professor gave us a very simple problem which was included in the lecture. he just wanted to see if we learned anything during the duration of the course. he just made us make a program to count the number of lines from a given text file. but in return only gave us a passing grade of 75%. props to everyone who helped. o think ill pass. :)

Comment: @tidibur That is a trivial problem in comparison. :) `perl -ne'END { print $. }' file.txt` in a one-liner. So he never admitted to giving you an impossible problem? Not even give a solution to show a "correct" example? That's weak.. :)

Answer (score 13):

Writing code to strip comments is not trivial, since the `#` character can be used in other contexts than just comments. Use [`perltidy`](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) instead:

```
perltidy --delete-block-comments --delete-side-comments foo
```

will strip `#` comments (but not POD) from file `foo` and write the output to `foo.tdy`. The shebang is not stripped.

Comment: @tidibur And I would like a pony. Regexes are not up to the task, and you're wasting your time to try. You can't even handle trivial cases reliably with regexes, due to string quoting and so forth.

Comment: @tidibur Then you will have to write a regex that accounts for all the different contexts in which `#` can be used: block comments (`# foo`), side comments (`my $foo; # foo`), strings (`my $foo = '#foo';`, `my $foo = q/#foo/;`, etc.), here-docs, arrays (`my $last = $#array;`), and so on. Don't reinvent the wheel (poorly).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i tried using this to skip the first occurrence:   `foreach $data(@data)
{ 
$data =~ s/#(?!\!\/)//g;
print "$data";
}` although i was able to save the path from being removed, the following occurrences only removed the "#" instead of the whole comment.

Comment: @tidibur That will badly mangle your source code, since you only remove the `#` and leave the comment text. Don't use a regex. This is a very complex problem, but it has already been solved.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes it is very complex. i hope to be able to find the solution or fail. :(

Comment: @tidibur I gave you a solution: perltidy.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i am only supposed to use regex. if i use perltidy, it would be void. would placing the occurrence of `#!/usr/bin/perl` in a variable and then `#comments` in another variable work?

Comment: @tidibur Is this a homework assignment? If so, ask your teacher if you're expected to handle the `#` inside strings, `__DATA__` blocks, POD, here-docs, arrays, etc., since it would be impossible to handle all of those cases with a regex.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot its a practical exam with given problems and then randomly drafted. hope this doesnt show up. we are only allowed to use regexes.

Comment: @tidibur That is a useless exam, created by a teacher with no knowledge in Perl. The problem is extremely complex, filled with edge cases. Even a trivial regex like yours will be extremely destructive on Perl code. You would have to restrict the style of the comment, for example `/^# /` (first on line, followed by space). But even this could fail in countless ways, such as for multiline strings or regexes. Tell your teacher that and he will be impressed. Or insulted, but hey, yolo.

Comment: @TLP hahaha! thanks but wouldnt do that if not drunk enough. :)

Comment: Interesting note about `PPI` is that `PPI::Token::Comment` matches the shebang line

Comment: @tidibur, What ThisSuitIsBlackNot means by "complex" is "pages and and pages long". It would takes weeks for an expert to write. I agree with TLP. Whoever wrote that exam's made a mistake. I can you find it unacceptable to fail to handle shebang lines, but find it acceptable to fail to handle `$#array`, `"#"`, `s#/#!#`, `#line 1000`, etc. YOUR PROGRAM WOULD FAIL TO WORK ON YOUR OWN PROGRAM!

Answer (score 3):

There is a method [`PPR::decomment()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPR#Decommenting-code-with-PPR::decomment()) that can be used:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PPR;

my $document = <<'EOF';
print "\n###################################\n";
print '\n###################################\n';
print '\nFollowed by comment \n'; # The comment
return $function && $function !~ /^[\s{}#]/;
EOF

my $res = PPR::decomment( $document );
print $res;
```

**Output**:

```
print "\n###################################\n";
print '\n###################################\n';
print '\nFollowed by comment \n'; 
return $function && $function !~ /^[\s{}#]/;
```

Comment: Looks good though how would I use it when I have the string in a variable while looping through a file?

Comment: You could try running `PPR::decomment()` on the variable?

Comment: Sorry to nag (as non perl programmer) but how would I do this say the string is in `$cleanline`?

Comment: No problem. Have you tried `PPR::docomment( $cleanline )` ?

Comment: I just did send my nagging comment and than I saw the `$res` line so I just wanted to write the comment: Oh stupid me, just `my $res = PPR::decomment( $cleanline);`. testing will take some time, I probably have to install PPR

Comment: I just encountered a small problem, the behavior is according to the PPR documentation but in my case not really wanted. According to the PPR documentation: "The subroutine will fail if the argument wasn't valid Perl code, in which case it returns undef and sets $PPR::ERROR to indicate where the invalid source code was encountered." and I run into this problem when I have a line like: `sub fie { # comment`, any brilliant ideas?

Comment: I just formulated a follow up question in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289457/strip-all-comment-from-perl-file-using-perl-ppr

Answer (score 2):

[`perltidy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/bin/perltidy) is the method to do this if it's anything but an exercise.  There's also [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) for parsing perl.  Could use the `PPI::Token::Comment` token to do something more complicated than just stripping.

However, to answer your direct question, don't try to solve everything in a single regex.  Instead, break up your problems into logic pieces of information and logic.  In this instead, if you want to skip the first line, do so by using line by line processing which conveniently sets the current line number in `$`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = '... your file...';

open my $fh, '<', $file;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ($. != 1) {
        s/#.*//;
    }

    print;
}
```

**Disclaimer**

The approach of using regex's for this problem is definitely flawed as everyone has already said.  However, I'm going to give your instructor the benefit of the doubt, and that she/he is aiming to teach by intentionally giving you a problem that is outside of the perview of regex's ability.  Good look finding all of those edge cases and figuring out how to do with them.

Whatever you do, don't try to solve them using a single regex.  Break your problem up and use lots of `if`'s and `elsif`'s

Comment: Aside from the obvious problems of breaking `$#array`, `"#"`, `s#/#!#g` and `#line 1000`, it doesn't remove comments (if any) on first line.

Comment: I should have said "Aside from the obvious problem that the program does not work on itself"!

Comment: @Miller short but clean code. very well done but this wont work if the shebang is placed on the 2nd line. although its pure common sense that it should always be first. ill give this a shot. thank you

Comment: @tidbur, You are mistaken. There cannot be such a thing as a shebang on the second line. By definition, the shebang (`#!`) must be the very first two characters of the file.

Comment: My solution isn't meant to be a "solution".  It's meant to suggest an approach to work on this, but you'll definitely need to add more logic.  Anyway, walking away from this, as I just wanted to give a nudge in a direction your instructor was obviously intending.

Comment: thanks to the both of you. will sure try to use both of your tips. :(

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a regex solution:

```
'' =~ /(?{
   system("perltidy", "--delete-block-comments", "--delete-side-comments", $file);
   die "Can't launch perltidy: $!\n"                   if $? == -1;
   die "perltidy killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
   die "perltidy exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  if $? >> 8;
});
```

---

It seems like you are leaning towards using the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
   if ($. != 1) {
      s/#.*//;
   }
   print;
}
```

But it doesn't work on itself:

```
$ chmod u+x stripper.pl

$ stripper.pl stripper.pl >stripped_stripper.pl

$ chmod u+x stripped_stripper.pl

$ stripped_stripper.pl stripper.pl
Substitution pattern not terminated at ./stripped_stripper.pl line 4.

$ cat stripped_stripper.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
   if ($. != 1) {
      s/
   }
   print;
}
```

It also fails to remove comments on the first line:

```
$ cat >first.pl
# This is my first Perl program!
print "Hello, World!\n";

$ stripper.pl first.pl
# This is my first Perl program!
print "Hello, World!\n";
```

Comment: thank you for the help but this way too complex for me to comprehend. i have only been learning perl for about a week.

Comment: It does exactly the same as if the first line and last line weren't there: It runs perltidy, and throws and reports any errors. You insisted it had to be in a regex, so there you go. If you can't understand that, how could you possibly write a Perl parser?

Comment: yep. sorry for that. i hope @miller's solution would suffice though. and thank you for your effort. :)

Comment: @Miller's solution doesn't work on Miller's solution.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. but only if the "shebang" is in the first line.. hmmm

Comment: @tidbur, Miller's solution doesn't have a shebang line. I was referring to the fact that it clobbers line 11.

Comment: thats because he used other functions. try this one:             `#!/usr/bin/perl
$file = $ARGV[0];

open F, $file;

while (<F>) {
    if ($. != 1) {
        s/#.*//;
    }

    print;
}` that is the one i used

Comment: @tidibur, That solution does not work on itself. (And you should just use `while (<>)`, which will read from the file passed as arg or from STDIN if none)

Comment: dude im telling u its working. tried it several times already. do try the solution i posted.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show that it's not working

Comment: now i understand what you're saying. your right man. I thought i got it right already. :(( thanks for showing that dude