# Strip all comment from perl file using perl / PPR

Tags: perl

I have a file with the following content:

```
sub is_top_level0 { # with comment
print '\nFollowed by comment \n'; # The comment

# line from begin
}
```

I'm, basically, using the following code where `$sFilename` is set to the right file name:

```
use PPR;

    open(DATAIN, $sFilename);
    my @aFileData = map({ s/\r$//g; $_; } <DATAIN>);
    close (DATAIN);
    my $aRawFileData= \@aFileData;
    printf("Read:\n@{$aRawFileData}===============\n");
    my $aUncommentFileData = PPR::decomment($aRawFileData);
    printf("Uncomment:\n@{$aUncommentFileData}===============\n");
```

The output is:

```
Read:
sub is_top_level0 { # with comment
 print '\nFollowed by comment \n'; # The comment

 # line from begin
 }
===============
Uncomment:
sub is_top_level0 { # with comment
 print '\nFollowed by comment \n'; # The comment

 # line from begin
 }
===============
```

as can be seen the part named "Uncomment" still contains the comments.

How to handle this?

(Note problem might sound a bit silly, but I'm not a perl programmer, just trying to modify some existing code)

Edit: small clarification as I wrote in the comment on the answer from @Dada (and that has been added in the answer as well):

> Probably not clear enough in the question, but I would like to have the data available in an array `$aRawFileData` and `$aUncommentFileData` (with the line terminators `\n`) so I can iterate over the arrays (as it is done at the moment).

Comment: tip: `map({ s/\r$//g; $_; } <DATAIN>)` would be clearer as `map { s/\r$//r } <DATAIN>` (assuming you haven't changed `$/` earlier, and that `/g` is thus useless; add a `/g` otherwise)

Comment: tip: use lexical file handle rather than global ones. _ie_, do `open my $DATAIN, '<', $sFilename` rather than `open DATAIN, '<', $sFilename`

Comment: tip: use 3-argument open rather than 2. _ie_, do `open my $DATAIN, '<', $sFilename` rather than `open my $DATAIN, '$sFilename'`

Comment: tip: check that `open` succeeded. _ie_, do `open my $DATAIN, '<', $sFilename or die "Could not open $sFilename: $!"`

Comment: Thanks for the tips very much appreciated, I'll have a look at it, but I want to change as little as possible in the existing program (as I'm not a perl programmer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PPR::decomment`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPR#Decommenting-code-with-PPR::decomment()) takes a string as argument, cf the documentation:

> It takes a single argument: a string containing the course code

Here, you are calling it on `$aRawFileData`, which is an arrayref (used as a string, it looks like `ARRAY(0x.....)`; which doesn't contain any `#` and is thus left as is by `PPR::decomment`)

Instead of reading your source code line by line, you should read it as a single string, store that in a variable, and pass it to `PPR::decomment`:

```
use File::Slurp;

my $sFilename = "test.pl";
my $source_code = read_file($sFilename);
my $without_comments = PPR::decomment($source_code);

print $without_comments;
```

You might want to still remove the `\r` after reading the file. In that case add

```
$source_code =~ s/\r$//g;
```

after reading your input.

I've used [`File::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) to read the whole file at once. If you'd like another method to do that, have a look at the question [What is the best way to slurp a file into a string in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206661/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-string-in-perl).

If you need the lines of your file in an array, you can then split your string:

```
my @lines = split /\n/, $without_comments;
```

If you want the newlines (`\n`) to be kept, then use:

```
my @lines = split /(?<=\n)/, $without_comments;
```

Comment: Probably not clear enough in the question, but I would like to have the data available in an array `$aRawFileData` and `$aUncommentFileData` (with the line terminators `\n`) so I can iterate over the arrays (as it is done at the moment).

Comment: @albert Not clear indeed :D I've edited my answer to do this (see at the end)

Comment: You don't want to process code line by line. You need the context of the preceding lines to know where you are in the code. Perl is not a line-oriented language.